# STACK.peek function, having some trouble, C++

Tags: c++, class, function, struct, tostring

```
CARD& STACK::peek()
{
    if(cards.size == 0)
    {
        CARD temp = CARD {-1, -1};
        return temp;
    }
    return cards.back();
}
```

This is the function I am having trouble with.

- `CARD` is just a `struct` with two `int` variables, called `rank` and `suit`.
- `STACK` is a `class` that manages an `std::vector<CARD>`, that is called `cards`.

The function is supposed to return a `reference` to the card on top of the stack, or return the reference to a dummy card if the `vector` is empty.

First of all, I get a warning that says a reference to a local variable `temp` is returned.  What is wrong with that?  How will that effect the function?  What do I do about it?

Second, I am trying to use this function with another function I created called `cardToString`

```
char* cardToString(CARD& c);
```

It is supposed to use the `rank` and `suit` variables in the passed `CARD` to look up string values in a table, concatenate the two strings together, and return a pointer to the new string.

So the end result looks like:

```
cout<<cardToString(deck.peek())<<"\n";
```

but this line of code will execute up to the `cardToString` function, then just stop for some reason.  It is annoying the hell out of me because it just stops, there is no error message and there does not look like there is anything wrong to me.

Can somebody help me out?

Edit: here is the `cardToString` function

```
char *cardToString(const CARD& c)
{
    if(c.r >= 13 || c.r < 0 || c.s >= 4 || c.s < 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"returned null";
        return NULL;
    }

    char *buffer = new char[32];

    strcpy(buffer, RANKS[c.r]);
    strcat(buffer, " of ");
    return strcat(buffer, SUITS[c.s]);
}
```

I specifically want the function `STACK.peek()` to return the address of the `CARD` that already exists on the top of the `STACK`. It seems to make more sense to do that than to create a copy of the card that I want to return.

Comment: Posting your `cardToString` function may help in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Returning by value vs. by reference vs. by pointer should be a decision of *semantics*. Semantically, returning by reference doesn't make any sense because one of the possible return values is, as you labeled it, temporary.

Comment: @ildjam The class could contain a dummy `CARD` that it returns a reference to (analogous to `std::string::npos`).

Answer (score 3):

> First of all, I get a warning that says a reference to a local variable `temp` is returned. What is wrong with that? How will that effect the function? What do i do about it?

A local variable, as it name implies, is local to the function it belongs to, so it's destroyed as the function returns; if you try to return a reference to it, you'll return a reference to something that will cease to exist at the very moment the function returns.

Although in some cases this may seem to work anyway, you're just being lucky because the stack hasn't been overwritten, just call some other function and you'll notice it will stop working.

You have two choices: first of all, you can return the `CARD` by value instead of reference; this, however, has the drawback of not allowing the caller to use the reference to modify the `CARD` as is stored in the `vector` (this may or may not be desirable).

Another approach is to have a static dummy `CARD` instance stored in the `STACK` class, that won't have these lifetime problems, and that can be returned when you don't have elements in the `vector`; however, you should find a method to "protect" its field, otherwise a "stupid" caller may change the values of your "singleton" dummy element, screwing up the logic of the class. A possibility is to change `CARD` in a `class` that will encapsulate its fields, and will deny write access to them if it's the dummy element.

As for the `cardToString` function, you're probably doing something wrong with the strings (and I'm almost sure you're trying to return a local also in this case), but without seeing the body of the function it's difficult to tell what.

By the way, to avoid many problems with strings I suggest you to use, instead of `char *`, the `std::string` class, which takes away most of the ugliness and of the low level memory management of the usual `char *`.

Also, I'd suggest you to change `cardToString` to take a `const` reference, because most probably it doesn't need to change the object passed as reference, and it's good practice to clearly mark this fact (the compiler will warn you if you try to change such reference).

---

***Edit***
The `cardToString` function should be working fine, as long as the `RANKS` and `SUITS` arrays are ok. *But*, if you used that function like you wrote, you're leaking memory, since for each call to `cardToString` you make an allocation with `new` that is never freed with `delete`; thus, you are losing 32 bytes of memory per call.

As stated before, my tip is to just use `std::string` and forget about these problems; your function becomes as simple as this:

```
std::string cardToString(const CARD& c)
{
    if(c.r >= 13 || c.r < 0 || c.s >= 4 || c.s < 0)
        return "(invalid card)";

    return std::string(RANKS[c.r]) + " of " + SUITS[c.s];
}
```

And you don't need to worry about memory leaks and memory allocations anymore.

---

For the reference/value thing: if the caller do not need to use the reference to modify the object stored in the vector, I strongly suggest passing it by value. The performance hit is negligible: two `int`s instead of one pointer means 8 vs 4 bytes on most 32 bit architectures, and 8 bytes vs 8 bytes on most 64 bit machines (and also accessing the fields via pointer has a small cost).

This kind of micro-optimization should be the last of your concerns. Your top priority is to write *correct* and *working* code, and the last thing you should do is to let micro-optimization get in the way of this aim.

Then, if you experience performance problems, you'll profile your application to find where the bottlenecks are and optimize those critical points.

Comment: thanks for the tip about memory leak, ill keep that in mind.  I would just use a string like you suggest but im trying to learn how to do it the long way.

Comment: @Morshu: the C++ way is `std::string`; leave `char *` and completely manual heap management to the C programmers.

Comment: well escuuuse me lol im just kidding thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a reference to a local variable, because the local variable no longer exists when the function returns.

You need to return by-value, not by-reference (i.e. `CARD STACK::peek() { ... }`).

Comment: Also `cardToString` needs to take a `CARD const&` rather than a `CARD&`, otherwise `cardToString(deck.peek())` won't work because `deck.peek()` will return an rvalue.